# C# pass keyword (interface) as parameter to the method

Tags: c#, generics, interface

Is it somehow possible to pass only a name of the interface to the method?

```
FindItems(IMyInterface);
```

I need to pass to the generic method the interface but without the object.
What it would look like:

```
public T FindItems<T>(T) where T : ISomeInterface
{
    //Magic that is searching for the object that implements given interface
    return magicObject;
}
```

It is possible to do that this way:

```
public T FindItems<T>(T obj) where T : ISomeInterface
{
    //Magic that is searching for the object that implements given interface
    return magicObject;
}
```

but then I would have to create object that implement the interface to only be deleted secound latter. Is there a better way?

Comment: Remove the parameter entirely; you already have the interface type as `T`. The corresponding `System.Type` can be obtained using `typeof(T)`.

Comment: `public T FindItems<T>() where T : ISomeInterface` and you call it like this `FindItems<IMyInterface>()` Your "magic" could be something like `return someList.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: @Charlieface ooo that's how I call it. I just was trying to figure out how to do that

Comment: In fact it's probable that `.OfType<IMyInterface>()` is all you need, rather than writing a method yourself. It's rare to have a `T` that you don't know is a collection at all.

Comment: @JeroenMostert this is the method for searching for the Scriptable Objects (files) in Unity that implements the specified interface.